# Referencing debug dlls while build Release version

Tags: c#, vb.net, debugging, configuration, release

I am trying to build a release version of my vb.net project. My project references multiple dlls(I have both release and debug versions of these dlls). When I build my project, I set my configuration to Release (obviously), but do I also need to reference my release dlls or is referencing my debug dlls the same? I am simply curious to know if this makes any difference or not.

Comment: Where are the these referenced assemblies (/dlls)?  Are they in other projects in the same solution, or somewhere else on your disk?  When you are working on your current project (coding, building, debugging), do you do things like step into the code in the other assemblies.  There are a couple of ways you can do this depending on what you are trying to do (from the GAC to NuGet to directly referencing an assembly on disk).  In general, you are better off pointing at release DLLs rather than debug-built assemblies.  Don't forget, the metadata should be the same.  Try to describe things more

Answer (score 0):

As far as calling the DLLs, it will work either way becuase PInvoke is being used to access the entry points (assuming that you are not trying to step-into the c code).  PInvoke loads DLLs based on file name and loads functions based on entry point name (via GetProcAddress).

As far as what you ship, make SURE you don't ship the debug DLLs for a multitude of reasons.
For instance:

- Debug code is slower.
- Native debug DLLs will reference other debug libraries that machines without visual studio installed will not have.
- Often, in debug code, there are assert() instructions and the like that you probably don't want in the shipping code.
- Other stuff I forgot to mention